# Add to cart function using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, redux, react-redux

I am building a search filter of sorts using Elasticsearch and ReactiveSearch for UI. 
Each result has an ID, title, etc that I can call to display it when a user searches. I need a button for each results, and when the user clicks it, it should 'add to cart' or something like that. I just need the clicked results to be shown in the next page.

The code below is my search field, and the results that are shown. I have an onclick function, but I don't know how to proceed after that. I think I need to use redux.

```
class Results extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <ReactiveBase
          app="datataglist"
          credentials="mRgWyoKGQ:f47be2a6-65d0-43b6-8aba-95dbd49eb882"
          url="https://scalr.api.appbase.io"
          >
              <DataSearch
              componentId="search"
              dataField={[
                  "maker_tag_name",
                  "maker_tag_name.autosuggest",
                  "maker_tag_name.keyword"
                ]}
                fieldWeights={[6, 2, 6]}
                fuzziness={1}
                highlightField={["maker_tag_name"]}
                placeholder="Search Tag Name"
                style={{
                    marginBottom: 20
                }}
                title="Maker Tag Name"
                />
                  <SelectedFilters /> 
                  <ReactiveList
                    componentId="results"
                    dataField="_score"
                    pagination={true}
                    react={{
                        and: ["system", "grouping", "unit", "search"]
                    }}
                    size={10}
                    noResults="No results were found..."
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                     />
          </ReactiveBase>
      );
  }
}

function getNestedValue(obj, path) {
    const keys = path.split(".");
    const currentObject = obj;
    const nestedValue = keys.reduce((value, key) => {
      if (value) {
        return value[key];
      }
      return "";
    }, currentObject);
    if (typeof nestedValue === "object") {
      return JSON.stringify(nestedValue);
    }
    return nestedValue;
  }

function renderItem(res, triggerClickAnalytics) {
    let { url, unit, title, system, score, proposed, id } = {
      title: "maker_tag_name",
      proposed: "proposed_standard_format",
      unit: "units",
      system: "system",
      score: "_score",
      url: "",
      id: "_id"
    };
    title = getNestedValue(res, title);
    system = getNestedValue(res, system);
    url = getNestedValue(res, url);
    unit = getNestedValue(res, unit);
    score = getNestedValue(res, score);
    proposed = getNestedValue(res, proposed);
    id = getNestedValue(res, id);



    return (
      <Row
        onClick={triggerClickAnalytics}
        type="flex"
        gutter={16}
        key={res._id}
        style={{ margin: "20px auto", borderBottom: "1px solid #ededed" }}
      >
        <Col style={{ width: "360px" }}>
          <h3
            style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: title || "Choose a valid Title Field"
            }}
          />
        </Col>
        <div style={{ padding: "20px" }} />
        <Col>
            <p
            style={{ fontSize: "1em", width: "300px" }}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: system || "Choose a valid Description Field"
            }}
            />
        </Col>
        <div style={{ padding: "10px" }} />
        <Col>
        <p
            style={{ fontSize: "1em" }}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: unit || "-"
            }}
          />
        </Col>
        <div style={{ padding: "10px" }} />
        <Col style={{ minWidth: "120px" }}>
          <p
            style={{ fontSize: "1em", width: "300px"}}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: proposed || "Choose a valid Description Field"
            }}
          />
        </Col>
        <div style={{ padding: "10px" }} />
        <Col>
          <p
            style={{ fontSize: "1em"}}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: Math.round(score) || "Choose a valid Description Field"
            }}
          />
        </Col>
        <Col>
            <Button
              shape="circle"
              icon={<CheckOutlined />}
              style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
              onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(id)}}
            />
        </Col>
        <Col style={{ minWidth: "120px" }}>
          <p
            style={{ fontSize: "1em", width: "300px"}}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: id || "Choose a valid Description Field"
            }}
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }


export default Results;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: when you say "next page" what do you mean? are you using react-router?

Comment: No, as in, once the user has selected all the results he wants to choose, it should be saved so the user can see it when he clicks 'submit'. That's why I said it's similar to an 'add to cart', where a user can see the selection on their checkout page.